# How to run a scheduled task in task scheduler through powers shell command

Tags: powershell, cmd, windows-task-scheduler

Any Powershell cmdlet to run scheduled task in task scheduler?

We have commands to Disable,Enable,Start,Stop the tasks in task schduler through powershell commands like below.But I didnt find any command to run a scheduled task which is in "Ready" state.Any idea?

```
Get-ScheduledTask -Taskpath "\TasksFolder\"|enable-ScheduledTask
Get-ScheduledTask -Taskpath "\TasksFolder\"|disble-ScheduledTask
Get-ScheduledTask -Taskpath "\TasksFolder\"|start-ScheduledTask
Get-ScheduledTask -Taskpath "\TasksFolder\"|stop-ScheduledTask
```

Comment: Your question isn't clear. If you have a scheduled task and want to run it, you should use [Start-ScheduledTask](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/scheduledtasks/start-scheduledtask?view=win10-ps)

Comment: Its not running...I want to get scheduled task to "Running" state from "Ready" state using powershell command or any command line script

Comment: That's what `Start-ScheduledTask` does - it starts the task, which will show as 'running' in the UI.  If it doesn't do that when you try, do you get any errors?  Does it work if you start it manually via the UI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following cmdlet to start a scheduled task from powershell:

```
Start-ScheduledTask -TaskPath "your task path" -TaskName "your task name"
```

To stop:

```
Stop-ScheduledTask -TaskPath "your task path" -TaskName "your task name"
```

Comment: Its not running...I want to get scheduled task to "Running" state from "Ready" state using powershell command or any command line script

Comment: Open task scheduler.exe, try running your task from the task scheduler manager, if the state changes from ready to running and stays that way same thing should happen with the commands I told you about earlier. If it runs then returns to ready or stays at ready then your issue is with the task or the time it runs is limited.